# How to get the hostname or mac add of currently connected remote host via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

When you login remotely via ssh you get a message like:

```
Last login: Thu Feb 26 12:28:42 2015 from zxin10-pc.private-net.com
```

This details are for the previous user. 
Is it possible to capture the domain name of the current remote user's machine while the ssh session is still on e.g. say HS-pc.private-net.com, and the ssh host is behind a firewall (using natted IP).

I've tried:

```
echo $SSH_CLIENT : $SSH_CONNECTION
```

but it only shows the IP address.

```
remoteip= $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1}'
dig -x $remoteip

; <<>> DiG 9.5.0-P2 <<>> -x 10.21.19.141
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I cannot use `arp` because `arp` doesn't go beyond the firewall.

Is there a way to get the domain name, hostname or MAC adddress of the remote user during their session?

Comment: You can use the `who am i` command. Does it work for you? However if behind `NAT` you'll only see the IP/hostname of the firewall.

Comment: You can use the `last` command. `last | awk '{print $3;exit}'`

Comment: Hostnames are looked up via DNS. It looks like DNS does not work for you either. Do you have an idea why that is? The MAC address your server sees cannot be useful to you because it is local to your server's network segment.

Comment: Hey Nazaf, last has no list of hostnames,

Comment: @Michael, the server is natted by the firewall, I have to confirm with network admin whether dns is blocked by firewall

Comment: The `remoteip` assignment contains multiple syntax errors.  I guess you really mean `dig -x "${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"`?  The output you print seems to indicate that you somehow managed to pass the right argument to `dig` but apparently by some other means then.

Comment: `last` looks in the same place as the login message so should definitely display the same hostname